# Function showing only one column average..?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

A little backstory: 
I have this homework that requires you to write a program using functions and pointers. You are supposed to enter the money each cinema hall earned throughout the summer. At one point, you need to find the average for each cinema hall and after that the average for each month (for example that would be summing up all the earning from July and dividing them by 5). I've done an okay job so far but I am stuck... The program works just fine but I cannot get it to show the values of all the 3 months. It just shows the average of the first month 3 times.. any suggestions to what I could change? Thank you so much for reading through this, here's a cookie and the code below.

```
#include "genlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"
#define row 5
#define col 3

void array(int array[row][col]);
void cinemaEarnings(int array[row][col], double *sum);
void columnEarnings(int array[row][col], int colAvg[]);


int main(){

    double sum;

    int array1[row][col];
    int array2[col];


    array(array1);

    cinemaEarnings(array1,&sum);

    columnEarnings(array1,array2);

    return 0;
}

void array(int array[row][col]){

    int i;
    int j;

    for (i=0; i<row; i++){
        printf("CINEMA HALL NUMBER %d\n", i+1);
        for (j=0; j<col; j++){
            printf("Monthly earnings for month number %d: ", j+1);
            array[j][i]=GetInteger();
        }
    }
}

void cinemaEarnings(int array[row][col], double *sum){

    int total;
    int i,j;
    *sum =0;

    for (j=0; j<row; j++){
        for (i=0; i<col; i++){
            *sum += array[i][j];
        }
        total = *sum / 3;
        printf("\nAverage earnings for hall %d: %d\n",j+1, total);
        *sum = 0;
    }
}

void columnEarnings(int array[row][col], int colAvg[]){

    int i,j;
    double sum;

    for (j=0; j<col; j++){
        sum = 0;
        for (i=0; i<row; i++){
            sum+=array[i][j];
            colAvg[j] = sum / row;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<col; i++){
        printf("\naverage for month number %d is : %d",i+1, colAvg[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `array[j][i]=GetInteger();` I think you want `array[i][j]=GetInteger();`, otherwise you write outside of the bounds of the array.

Comment: `colAvg[j] = sum / row;` Um... why is that in the *inner* for loop in `columnEarnings` ?

Comment: Your code would be easier to follow if you changed `row` to `hall` and `col` to `month` - or something similar. Also, fix the indentation.

Comment: @WhozCraig should it not be in the inner loop? When I put it outside that loop, it has the same effect as when it was in the inner. If I get it completely out of both of the loops it goes crazy.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Sorry I forgot to mention that I need help with the "columnEarnings". The rest is working fine.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Ah yeah that would definitely make it look much better. Could you elaborate on the "fix the indentation"?

Comment: @VaggelisDavios WhozCraig has already fixed the indentation for you. Notice how the brackets line up and the code inside the loops is tabbed over to the right to show it is part of the loop. This doesn't affect how the code runs. It just makes it easier to read.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp ah now I get it. Thank you so much @WhozCraig! Anything else you guys would suggest?

Comment: @VaggelisDavios `colAvg[j] = sum / row` should be done inside the outer `j` loop, but outside the inner `i` loop.  The inner loop has one purpose: compute the sum. The outer loop has two purposes: use the inner loop to compute the sum, then use that resulting sum to compute the column average, storing it in `colAvg[j]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColumnErnings function has a basic error on index. Look at last for loop, you loop on index "i" and the use index "j" on "colAvg[j]". The correct function is the following:

```
void columnEarnings(int array[row][col], int colAvg[]){

    int i,j;
    double sum;

    for (j=0; j<col; j++){
        sum = 0;
        for (i=0; i<row; i++){
            sum+=array[i][j];
            colAvg[j] = sum / row;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<col; i++){
        printf("\naverage for month number %d is : %d",i+1, colAvg[i]);
    }
}
```

in addition you can move "colAvg[j] = sum / row;" instruction outside the nested for in this way:

```
void columnEarnings(int array[row][col], int colAvg[]){

        int i,j;
        double sum;

        for (j=0; j<col; j++){
            sum = 0;
            for (i=0; i<row; i++){
                sum+=array[i][j];                    
            }
            colAvg[j] = sum / row;
        }
        for (i=0; i<col; i++){
            printf("\naverage for month number %d is : %d",i+1, colAvg[i]);
        }
    }
```

in this way you avoid to update a variable that has no sense in intermediate step.